# How do i get rid of the bottom iMessage app toolbar in iOS 11?

Tags: messages, ios

I don't use the iMessage apps very often. How do I get rid of it to free up some screen real estate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you tap and hold the gray App Store button for a bit right above the bottom toolbar that should remove the bar until you call it up explicitly with the same button.